# Limiting results with Jinja (Python)

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there anyway in Jinja to limit results that are displayed based on the format?

For example if I had a CSV with the following data:

```
Agent ID DOB
152      31/07/1993
175      05/12/1997
```

With a template setup like so:

```
filename = self._Report(self.date, self.time_from, self.time_to)
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')
template = env.get_template('testtemplate.html')

rdr = csv.DictReader( open(filename, "r" ) )
csv_data = [ row for row in rdr ]

return template.render( data=csv_data )
```

And a template like so:

```
{% for row in data %}
<td>{{ row['Agent ID']] }}</td>
<td>{{ row['DOB']]</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Say if I just wanted to present data for Agent ID 152?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't filter the data in Jinja. Filter the data in Python:

```
csv_data = [row for row in rdr if row['Agent ID'] == '152']
```

That still produces a list; if you expected just one result, you can limit the reading of CSV data to find just the first match:

```
csv_data = next((row for row in rdr if row['Agent ID'] == '152'), {})
```

This now produces *one dictionary*, the first row matching the Agent ID, or an empty dictionary if no such row exists. Reading stops at the first match.

Comment: Thanks alot! Need to wait 9 minutes before I can accept the answer.

Comment: Also @Martijn, What would I do if I wanted to filter down to multiple agents? == '152,154,158,147' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `row['Agent ID'] in ('152', '154', '158', '147')`, and remove the `next` wrapping it, you will have a list then.

Comment: @LukeLivingstone: use a membership test with `row['Agent ID'] in {'152', '154', '158', '147'}`. That'll test against a set of numbers.

Comment: @RafaelBarros: it'd work with the `next()` call too, but would only find the first match. The answer already states that the first option, using a list comprehension, would find all matches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then I misinterpreted his question about "filtering down to multiple agents".

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestions guys! All fixed now!